# How to create an organized git repository for an Android project that uses a git submodule

Tags: android, git, git-submodules

My android project depends on 3rd party libs from github (which I will add as git submodules).
I want to come to a point where cloning the project will retrieve all of the relevant projects AND that everything will be organised in my work space (I'm using eclipse).

What is the recommended way to build such a repository?

I had this in mind:

```
- project_main (repo root)
   - libs
       - 3rd part lib1
       - 3rd part lib2
       - ...
   - android_project
       - src
       - libs
       - res
       - ...
```

And as an alternative the root can be the android project into which the 3rd party libs will be cloned:

```
- android_project (repo root)
    - src
    - libs
    - res
    - ...
    - 3rd part lib1
    - 3rd part lib2
    - ...
```